# python Tkinter grid method not working as should be for some reason

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter

i am trying to get my listbox to move to the bottom of the gui but no matter how high of a row value i give it it wont budge. you can see my listbox in the Creat_Gui method in my code. im not sure why this is happpening it cant be the button because the button is in row 1 so im not sure whats causing this.

i tried using sticky='s' that didnt work i tried changing the rows multiple times didnt work. i tried using the root.rowconfigure(100,weight=1) this worked kind of but messes with thte grid which is annoying

```
import tkinter as tk

class Manager:
    def __init__(self):
        self.root=tk.Tk()

        self.root.title('password_manager')
        self.root.geometry('500x600')

        self.create_GUI()
        self.storage = {}
        self.root.mainloop()


    def create(self):
        pass

    def open_page(self):
        print('openpage')
    def add_new_button(self):
        pass
    def add_new(self):
        self.app_title=tk.Label(text='test')
        self.app_title.grid(row=2,column=50)
        self.application_name=tk.Entry(self.root,width=20,font=('arial',18))
        self.username=tk.Entry(self.root,width=20,font=('arial',18))
        self.password=tk.Entry(self.root,width=20,font=('arial',18))
        self.application_name.grid(row=2, column=1)
        self.username.grid(row=3, column=2)
        self.password.grid(row=4, column=3)

        self.app_name_label = tk.Label(self.root, text='Application Name:')
        self.username_label = tk.Label(self.root, text='Username:')
        self.password_label = tk.Label(self.root, text='Password:')

        self.app_name_label.grid(row=2, column=0)
        self.username_label.grid(row=3, column=1)
        self.password_label.grid(row=4, column=2)

        self.password.bind('<Return>',self.hide)
    def hide(self,thing):
        #store user info to pass onto dictionary and hide textboxes
        username=self.username.get()
        password=self.password.get()
        app_name=self.application_name.get()
        self.application_name.grid_forget()
        self.username.grid_forget()
        self.password.grid_forget()
        self.add_to_memory(username,password,app_name)

    def add_to_memory(self,username,password,app_name):
        #store username password and application name in dictionary
        if app_name in self.storage.keys():
            return
        else:
            self.storage[app_name]=(username,password)
        print(self.storage)
    def create_GUI(self):
        #create initial interface
        #self.root.columnconfigure(100, weight=1)
        #self.root.rowconfigure(100, weight=1)
        self.listbox=tk.Listbox(self.root,width=100)

        self.listbox.grid(row=200,column=0)
        self.button=tk.Button(self.root,text='add new',font=('arial',18),command=self.add_new)
        self.button.grid(row=1,column=0)


Manager()
```

Comment: Are you aware that empty rows and empty columns have a size of zero?

Comment: what do you mean by this @BryanOakley

Comment: That means putting it in row 200 is the same as putting it in row 2 if there is nothin in rows 2-199

Comment: ok I see what you mean but how come the list box doesn't appear at the bottom of the page

Comment: because you set your window to be 500x600 and you only have 2 widgets in the window.  you either need to extend your listbox height, add more widgets above the listbox, or dont use the grid. or set the rowspan. or make the window smaller

Comment: so there is no way to move it down ?

Comment: ok so by adding more widgets above this one so if I added something in row 2 and move the listbox to row 3 it would move lower and the window size needs to be changed to fit the widgets in properly thanks for help

Comment: This is what is commonly referred to as an [xy problem](https://xyproblem.info/) it would be better if you described what your actual goal is.

Comment: ok my overall question is how to move a list box to the bottom of a page does that make it more clear

Comment: LOL... no.  What would have made it more clear is to explain why you want it moved to the bottom.  What is the end result, because there are lots of ways to move a widget to the bottom, but many probably don't make sense for what you are trying to achieve. That being said @BryanOakley answer should do the trick

Comment: lmao ok my bad im new but ya his answer works for what I wanted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use grid, and you want a widget to be at the bottom of it's parent, you need to designate some row above that widget to take all of the extra space, forcing the widget to the bottom. Here's one example:

```
def create_GUI(self):
    self.listbox=tk.Listbox(self.root,width=100)
    self.expando_frame = tk.Frame(self.root)
    self.button=tk.Button(self.root,text='add new',font=('arial',18),command=self.add_new)

    self.root.grid_rowconfigure(2, weight=1)
    self.button.grid(row=1,column=0)
    self.expando_frame.grid(row=2, sticky="nsew")
    self.listbox.grid(row=3,column=0)
```

With that, the listbox will be at the bottom, with extra space above it. If you want to add more widgets, you can add them to `self.expando_frame` rather than `self.root` and they will appear above the listbox.

Using frames in this way is a valuable technique. You could, for example, use three frames in root: one for the top row of buttons, one for the listbox on the bottom, and one for everything in the middle. You could then use `pack` on these frames and save a line of code (by virtue of not having to configure the rows). You can then use `grid` for widgets inside the middle frame.